# Use "q" inside a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, q

i'm trying to get some data out of a Mssql server. I have a function with a loop. This function returned some data to the callback. How can i put the data from kriskowal's "q" to the *resultset* variable?

The functions *pet.getNameByID* and *adress.getNameByID* returned data to callbacks to!

Thanks for the help!

Greetings Nils

```
exports.get = function(callback) {
edge.func("sql", {
    source: 'SELECT * FROM people'
})(null, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        throw (error)
    }

    if (result) {

        var resultset = []

        for (var i in result) {

            var row = result[i];

            q.all([
                // get pet name
                q.fcall(function() {
                    var deferred = q.defer();
                    pet.getNameByID({
                        id: 32155
                    }, function(data) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    });
                    return deferred.promise;
                }),
                // get adress
                q.fcall(function() {
                    var deferred = q.defer();
                    adress.getNameByID({
                        id: 23
                    }, function(data) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    });
                    return deferred.promise;
                }),
            ]).spread(function(resultPet, resultAdress) {

                // Data!!!!
                return {
                    petData: resultPet,
                    adressData: resultAdress
                };

            });

            resultset.push( /* How can i push the data return from spread() into the resultset array? */ )
        }

        callback(resultset);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use another `Q.all`?

Comment: i use q.all in the second row after "for (var...". Or is there a beter solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your structure at some points still looks like a synchronous approach. I tried to change it below:

```
exports.get = function(callback) {
edge.func("sql", {
    source: 'SELECT * FROM people'
})(null, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
        return;
    }

    if (result) {

        var subresults = [];

        for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {

            var row = result[i];

            // defers for the results of the subqueries
            var petResult = q.defer(),
                adressResult = q.defer();

            // 1st subquery
            pet.getNameByID({
                id: 32155
            }, function(data) {
              petResult.resolve(data);
            });

            // 2nd subquery
            adress.getNameByID({
                id: 23
            }, function(data) {
                adressResult.resolve(data);
            });

            // collect both subquerys and add a promise for
            var subqueries = q.all( petResult.promise, adressResult.promise )
                                .then( function( pet, adress ){
                                  return {
                                    petData: pet,
                                    adressData: adress
                                  }
                                }, function( e ){ 
                                  return e 
                                });

            // collect all subresults
            subresults.push( subqueries );
        }

        // when all queries are resolved
        q.all( subresults )
         .then( function(){
          // all results will be in the arguments array here
          callback( arguments );
         }, function( e ) {
           // some error handling
         });

    }
});
});
```

The calls to `adress.getNameByID()` and `pet.getNameByID()` are async as well and should be treated as such. So in my code I get both the results for those subqueries and combine them to a new deferred/promise. When all those subquery promises are fullfilled, one can execute the main callback with the respective results.

Comment: Why iterate an array with a for... in loop? Also, why the callback?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Both just part of OPs code I didn't change.